# Add column for select with the checkbox,column name "select", and one button for delete selection dates

Tags: reactjs, typescript, laravel, react-typescript, inertiajs

To select, we need to add a column with a checkbox, the column name is "Select", at the top right of the Offers page, we need to have another button "Delete Selected", which should be inactive until the row is selected.I can't do it.

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState<number[]>([]);

    const handleCheckboxChange = (id: number, checked: boolean) => {
        if (checked) {
            setSelected([...selected, id]);
        } else {
            setSelected(selected.filter((item) => item !== id));
        }
};
```

Comment: You should provide the implementation of the onChange handler, otherwise it's hard to reproduce the problem.